# wordpress custom role is not performing properly

Tags: wordpress

I wrote the following code for adding a custom role who can only moderate the comments in wordpress.

```
 function simple_role_for_comments_only() {
    add_role( 'comment-moderator', 'Comments Moderator',
                array(
                    'read' => true,
                    'update_core' => false,
                    'edit_posts' => true
    ));
 }
 register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'simple_role_for_comments_only' );
```

But with `comment-moderator` role one can not moderate the comments just can read it. What I missed? Please suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [`moderate_comments`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#moderate_comments) is what you are missing

```
 function simple_role_for_comments_only() {
    add_role( 'comment-moderator', 'Comments Moderator',
                array(
                    'read' => true,
                    'update_core' => false,
                    'edit_posts' => true,
                    'moderate_comments' => true
    ));
 }
 register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'simple_role_for_comments_only' );
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have added `moderate_comments` but it is not working even now.